# split with same pattern structure (!)|(!\?) and (!)|(e!) But behave differently in python regex

Tags: python, regex

The sentence I want to split is this.

`sentence = "Break!me!?haha"`

And the first pattern is

`pattern = r'(!)|(!\?)'`

The result with these code are

```
print(re.split(pattern,sentence))
print([word for word in re.split(pattern, sentence) if word != None and not word == ""])
```

```
['Break', '!', None, 'me', '!', None, '?haha']
['Break', '!', 'me', '!', '?haha']
```

The `!` and `?` are used as delimiters. not `!` and `!?`.

But when I use this pattern

`pattern = r'(!)|(e!)'`

the result with same above codes are

```
['Break', '!', None, 'm', None, 'e!', '?haha']
['Break', '!', 'm', 'e!', '?haha']
```

This time delimiters were `!` and `e!`

But I think those patterns are using same structure.

```
pattern = r'(!)|(!\?)'
pattern = r'(!)|(e!)'
```

Here is working code

https://www.online-python.com/UrgFEQVCvR

Answer (score 1):

The patterns are differently structured - in the first pattern, the two alternatives share the same starting character, so the first alternative (`(!)`) will match first, whereas in the second pattern, they don't, so the second alternative matches first (because `e!` can be matched before `!`).

If you want `(!\?)` to take precedence over `(!)`, you need to place it first:

```
pattern = r'(!\?)|(!)'
```

(although you could simply use

```
pattern = r'(!\??)'
```

instead because the `?` is greedy).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The real problem I wanted to solve was this[link](https://www.online-python.com/zEP2A9nydS). I understand that the order of pattern matters, But Why in this case the order changes nothing?

Comment: What is your desired output with the linked example?

Comment: @tshiono There are no desired output. I just wonder why the order working differently in those cases. I can't upload a new question right now.
So I made a mark down file. Can I ask this[link](https://github.com/syha6821/temp/wiki) question?

Comment: As for `pattern = r'(\*)|\s|(".*?")'`, an asterisk within the double quotes *does not*
match the former `(\*)` because the latter `(".*?")` slurps it first.

Answer (score 0):

For the pattern `pattern = r'(!)|(!\?)'`, the way regex processes the pattern makes it so that it will only attempt to match `(!\?)` if it does not match `(!)`. Obviously, if it does not match `(!)` it will never match `(!\?)`. Flipping the statement around:

```
sentence = "Break!me!?haha"
pattern = r'(!\?)|(!)'

import re

print(re.split(pattern,sentence))
print([word for word in re.split(pattern, sentence) if word != None and not word == ""])

#output
['Break', None, '!', 'me', '!?', None, 'haha']
['Break', '!', 'me', '!?', 'haha']
```

For the second pattern `pattern = r'(!)|(e!)'`, you could possibly fail to match `(!)` but do match `(e!)`, which is exactly what occurs.

Comment: But In this[link](https://github.com/syha6821/temp/wiki) case, the order seems not working. Can I ask this question on that link? Right now I can't write a new question :(